# How does Spring Security BadCredentialsException mapped to HTTP 401 code

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, http-status-codes

When i throw a `org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException` exception, in client it will display `401` as below,

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-03-29T09:07:50.866+0000",
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Some message",
  "path": "/test/service1/getAll"
}
```

I want to know where and how does the `BadCredentialsException` mapped to `HTTP 401` Status code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java) that handles exceptions thrown by the security interceptors and provides suitable HTTP responses:

> The `ExceptionTranslationFilter` sits above the
>   `FilterSecurityInterceptor` in the security filter stack. It doesn’t do
>   any actual security enforcement itself, but handles exceptions thrown
>   by the security interceptors and provides suitable and HTTP responses.

Check out the Spring Security documentation for more information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#exception-translation-filter) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#exceptiontranslationfilter).